# What libraries should I use for linear programming in python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

A quick search on "python linear programming" turns up a lot of hits (e.g. [this one](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NumericAndScientific/Libraries)).  Looking through them, I see [a fair number of complaints](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/a6759eb75b35a40f?pli=1) about outdated dependencies, poor documentation, etc.

Can anybody recommend a headache-free (e.g. fast, well-documented, easy-to-install, clean API) linear programming library for python?

Comment: here's a few more ... http://www.scipy.org/Topical_Software

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [PULP](http://code.google.com/p/pulp-or/) and/or [Pyomo](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/coopr/wiki/Pyomo).

Comment: Are these suitable for large instances, lets say at least hundereds of variables and thousands of constraints.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure about how PULP and Pyomo scale for large problems. However, I can say that most of my friends who do huge optimization problems (mostly for integrated circuit layouts) use IBM CPLEX as their optimization solver. Based on a quick google search, there is a CPLEX API for Python. However, CPLEX isn't free for non-academic use.

Comment: ...I just checked your stackexchange profile, Andreas, and it looks like you're a graduate student. You can get a free CPLEX license. :)

Comment: @solvingPuzzles, would you know offhand if either of these has an API to NumPy arrays, along the lines `lpmin( x, A, c, lo, hi )` ?

Comment: Good question. I'm not really sure...I haven't hacked around with optimization stuff in a few months, so I'm a bit out of touch at this point.

Answer (score 5):

[cvxopt](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/) is written by Lieven Vandenberghe and some of his collaborators. (This is the same Vandenberghe of the widely used convex optimization textbook by Boyd and Vandenberghe.) It's a general convex conic programming solver, and uses an interior point method. On the plus side it's well-documented, has many examples, and is easy to use. I believe it scales fairly well, though not as well as commercial products like Xpress, Gurobi, or cplex.

Looks like there's a pull request to scipy containing a (pure python) linear programming implementation, though. So a linear programming solver could be in scipy in the future.

Comment: For the record, here is that PR https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/218

Answer (score 2):

You might look at PuLP from the coin-or set of libraries.

http://www.coin-or.org/projects/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are specifically trying to do, but NumPy/SciPy are the usually first places to look for anything math related in Python.

Comment: Numpy is an array library, with some extra functionality tossed in for backwards compatibility. Scipy has some optimization routines, but as of now I think it's only general non-linear solvers. Scipy does not currently have a solver specialized for linear programs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [or-tools](https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/), which includes a wrapper around widely used linear solvers such as [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).

Answer (score 1):

As of 2015, [scipy](http://scipy.org) includes a method to solve linear programming models directly through [scipy.optimize.linprog](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html#scipy.optimize.linprog). It uses the Simplex algorithm.